# Significantly different count between Google Sheets and SQL

Tags: sql, vlookup, counting

Getting two different counts between Google sheets and sql. After looking at the v lookup code and the sql code I can’t find any difference in the logic.  Main differences is that in the Google sheets a countif is totaling the results of a vlookup where in sql im calculating everything in 1 query by leveraging a subquery. Can anyone give me some reasons this may be happening. I’m currently getting a much higher number in sql

Sql code is as follows:

```
Select count(primary key)    
From table    
Where concat(col1, “ “, col2, “ “, col3) in
    (select concat(col1, “ “, col2, “ “, col3) 
     From table
     Where col1 <> “NULL” and col5 = “yes”
     Group by col1, col2, col3
     Having count(Distinct col4) > 1)
```

I tried getting rid of null values and tracing back the formulas on Google sheets and it couldn’t be resolved.

Edited: In google sheets I pulled from a pivot table that did the exact same thing as the subquery group by.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | PB | Sweet | 1 |
| Orange | Caramel | Sour | 2 |

I created another column to concatenate col 1, col2, and col3 since those are the values I wanted to group by in the vlookup. These columns existed in another dataset where I used a vlookup to pull from this dataset and determine if a row was greater than 1 or not. The vlookup formula is as follows:

=if(And(vlookup(cell, pivotdata, 4) >1, cell = "Yes), "Yes", "No")

After this formula I ran a count if to determine any rows that returned yes based on the formula.

Comment: `Where col1 <> “NULL”`? `col1 is not null` is the correct way to 'get rid of null values'.

Comment: you need to show als why you have done in sheets, maybe the logic is not equal

Comment: Edited above let me know if further clarification is requred